# How to add view filter programmatically using hook_views_pre_view()

Tags: views, hooks, 9

I want to add a simple filter to an existing view in Drupal 9. It appears that I can achieve this with `hook_views_pre_view()`. In every example I can find, including all the "Similar questions" links that come up when entering the title of this post, I see that `$view->add_item()` is used.  See: [Add views exposed filter programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256544/add-views-exposed-filter-programmatically)

However, when I try to run this code:

```php
function sbn_views_pre_view($view, $display_id, array $args) {
  if ($view->id() == 'draft_moderation_state') {
    // Get array of draft nids
    $state = 'draft';
    $results = sbn_get_all_nodes_in_moderation_state($state);

     // There is no draft_moderation_state filter so we have to add it
      $view->add_item(
        $view->current_display,
        'filter',
        'node',
        'nid',
        array(
          'operator' => '=',
          'value' => '59',
          'group' => 1
        )
      );
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Call to undefined method Drupal\views\ViewExecutable::add_item()

What is the command to add filter in `hook_views_pre_view()` in Drupal 9?

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to know how to add a filter using hook_views_pre_view(), but I solved my bigger problem (programmatically filtering an existing view) using

> hook_views_query_alter()

```
function sbn_views_query_alter($view, $query) {
   if ($view->id() == 'draft_moderation_state') {    
      $field = 'node_field_data.nid';
      // Get array of draft nids
      $state = 'draft';
      $value = sbn_get_all_nodes_in_moderation_state($state);
      $operator = 'IN';
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = [
        "field"    => $field,
        "value"    => $value,
        "operator" => $operator,
      ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$view->setHandler()` worked for me. I think this should be equivalent to the code in your question:

```php
$nid_filter = [
  'id' => 'nid',
  'table' => 'node_field_data',
  'field' => 'nid',
  'value' => ['value' => 59],
  'operator' => '=',
];
$view->setHandler($view->current_display, 'filter', 'nid', $nid_filter);
```

Answer (score -1):

$view->add_item(...) is Drupal 7

It's Drupal 7 vs Drupal 9 issue:

- D7: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/views_db_object%3A%3Aadd_item/7.x-3.x
- D9: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/8.2.x

it would be helpful if users of this forum would put a version of Drupal when they post questions.

Comment: My bad.  What is the command to add filter in hook_views_pre_view() in Drupal 9?